Is it possible to update markerclusters when markers changes position without clearing markers?
So I have map with vehicle positions that updates its markers every minute using marker.setPosition({lat: newPoint.lat, lng: newPoint.lng}) from a list of markers added on initial load.
These are clustered with @googlemaps/markerclusterer and after I've moved the markers I do this to update the clusters
    this.markerCluster.clearMarkers();
    this.markerCluster.addMarkers(this.markers);

However this causes all clusters and markers to blink. Which I've been told is annoying  and I was wondering if there was anything I could do to update it without this blinking?

The marker has a renderer that returns this marker if there's anything I can do there
new Marker({
  label: { 
    text: `${cluster.count}`, 
    color: isSelected || hasSelectedMarker ? "white" : "black", 
    fontWeight: "bold", 
    className: "group-marker",
    fontSize: "17px"
  },
  opacity: isOpaque ? 1 : MARKER_DESELECTED_OPACITY,
  icon,
  position: cluster.position,
  zIndex: Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX) + cluster.count,
});

